# "Cleaning..." phase when deleting apps

Tags: ios, beta

I am currently on iOS 12 beta 2. I noticed a new phase when deleting apps and was wondering what it is and what it's doing.

After pressing the "X" on the app I want to delete and select "Delete" on the dialog box, for a split second the text of the App name changes to "Cleaning...". It then changes back to the name of the App and it disappears as usual.

[image]

**What is this feature and what does it do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app that shows a `cleaning...` label under the icon means that it is currently deleting local data such as cache and temporary files associated with the app.

This process usually takes place when your device is low in memory or just before an iCloud Backup begins. Its purpose is to free up some space.

However, I never saw this while deleting an app, it may be either a bug or a new feature that warn the user that both the app and its data is being removed from the device.

---

**Sources** : [iMore](https://www.imore.com/facebook-apps-cleaning), [Cult Of Mac](https://www.cultofmac.com/136741/why-do-ios-5-apps-sometimes-say-they-are-cleaning-themselves/), [iPhone FAQ](https://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971692)

Comment: Any source? '''

Comment: Unfortunately I never found an absolute source such as Apple documentation. However, this behavior is explained on specialized websites in the same way as I proposed above since 2011 (iOS5) ([here](https://www.imore.com/facebook-apps-cleaning), [here](https://www.cultofmac.com/136741/why-do-ios-5-apps-sometimes-say-they-are-cleaning-themselves/) and [here](https://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971692)). They don't provide sources either but I think it is safe to trust this information since the app size is indeed reduced after the cleaning.

Comment: If you really want a reliable source you should contact Apple Support.

Comment: Those are find sources can you edit them into your answer. Then I’ll mark it as answered. Thanks!